# Using a formset to create links to records

Tags: python, django, templates, url

I'm using Django version 3.0.1, python version 3.6.9

I am trying to set urls to individual records in a loop inside a formset but the url tag can't see my variable even though it is printed out in the first table cell before I add the second line :

```
{# This displays correctly the integer id #}
<td>{{ form.record_id.value }}</td>

{# This next line doesn't work, though the above TD does display the record_id #}
<td><a href="{% url 'record_detail' form.record_id.value %}">{{ form.name.value }}</a></td>
```

The error I get is this as the page is rendered:

```
Reverse for 'record_detail' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['myapp\\/record_detail\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

This is my template table code (note the second line is commented out otherwise I get the error message on viewing the page):

```
<table id="formset" class="form">
{% for form in recordFormset.forms %}

  <tr class="someclass">
    <td>{{ form.record_id.value }}</td>

    {# This next line doesn't work, though the above TD does display the record_id #}
    {# <td><a href="{% url 'record_detail' form.record_id.value %}">{{ form.name.value }}</a></td> #}

  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

I am guessing this is because the url is created before the for loop through the formset's forms, but how then can I create these urls that I need to create?

(Please note I omitted the editable form fields in the above snippet just for brevity).

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up taking an entirely different approach.  I have created a widget which I used in a form field, the widget has a template with the hyperlink in it.  I populate the data for the link in the view before the page is rendered.